# (iOS) Create a simulator build for Facebook

Tags: ios, build, simulator

I have to upload a Simulator build on Facebook.

I have followed this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced

But I really can't get the step #2, which says:

```
"Zip the simulator build via the following command:"
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip
```

What does "path/to/YourApp.zip" refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have to convert your app into the zip file.You can do that without running this code or using terminal.

Below are steps to create app simulator build for Facebook

**Step 1**: Build and run your app in the iPhone  simulator. This automatically creates a simulator build in Xcode's “DerivedData” cache.

**Steo 2:** Open Terminal and navigate to the folder containing the Xcode project (something like build__iosnativedebug_xcode.

**Step 3:** Run the following to zip your build:
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip
**(In this step you can simply go to the dervied data and right click on the file and compress it .Using this you can also create zip file.no need to run this command.)**

Upload your zip file and follow the [steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit) here. You can submit a single build for reviewing all types of permissions (login, App Center, etc)

May be it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Bhumica, I have uploaded the .zip. I'll let you know as soon as I hear something from Facebook!

Answer (score 2):

**path/to/YourApp.zip** is the path of your output file. Another way, it is where you want to place the zip file (output file)